# Cannot use same razor page for two addresses

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I what to use the same razor page in more than one position in my web app.

I have the page `/one` and I want to reach also with `/two` and `/three`.

I can do it with the AddPageRoute :

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/one", "two");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/one", "three");
```

But the taghelpers in the page always render `formaction="/three?handler=Update"` pointing to the last route, same for `/one`, `/two` or `/three`

This make impossible use the same razor page in different position in my web application.

Git sample : https://github.com/enricoe73/OnePage2Routes.git

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the page using any of the routes you defined, but the outbound URL generation components in the framework (tag helpers, IUrlHelper etc) will always use the last route registered when generating an outbound URL, so the order in which the routes are registered plays a part.

If that doesn't suit you (because you may want to point to different routes at different times, for instance), the solution is to use the standard HTML `formaction` attribute instead of the custom `asp-*` attributes that belong to the tag helper:

`<button formaction="/two?handler=update">Update</button>`